# Problem foreach Windows Forms in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#

I have a problem, and my problem is the following: I have this code in C# and I don't know how to do a foreach to get all pakFilename

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

string strpagecode = client.DownloadString("https://fortnite-api.com/v2/aes");
dynamic dobj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(strpagecode);
string description = dobj["data"]["dynamicsKeys"][0]["pakFilename"].ToString();
aes.Text = description;
```

Could someone help me?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: are you using newtonjson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it would help to use real objects instead of dealing with `dynamic`.

Generate c# classes from the JSON. Paste your json string to a tool like https://json2csharp.com/.

The following classes are generated:

```
public class DynamicKey
{
    public string PakFilename { get; set; }
    public string PakGuid { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string Build { get; set; }
    public string MainKey { get; set; }
    public List<DynamicKey> DynamicKeys { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public Data Data { get; set; }
}
```

Afterwards you could easily deal with these objects:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string strpagecode = client.DownloadString("https://fortnite-api.com/v2/aes");
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(strpagecode);
List<string>? pakFileNames = myDeserializedClass.Data.DynamicKeys.Select(x => x.PakFilename).ToList();

// add to textbox
aes.text = string.Join("\n", pakFileNames);
```

This should give you the list of all `pakFileNames`:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, but how do I add it to a textbox.text = ?

Comment: if you like to flatten the array use: `textbox.text = string.Join("\n", pakFileNames);`. If you like to have newlines try `\n` as the separator. Maybe you need to play around according to your use case. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
var dynamicsKeys = dobj["data"]["dynamicsKeys"];
foreach(var dynamicsKey in dynamicsKeys) {
    string pakFilename = dynamicsKeys["pakFilename"].ToString()
}
```